# Java y sql (Connector J)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mysqlconnector

Estoy intentando trabajar con Java haciendo uso de MySQL Connector/J, pero me ha salido un error que no consigo solucionar:

```
    public static void new_User(String email, String password, String name){
    String sql = "INSERT INTO user (email, password, name) VALUES (" + email + ", " + password + ", " + name + ")";
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

La apertura de la conexión es correcta

```
        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + DB_SERVER + ":" + DB_PORT + "/" + DB_NAME;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        if(conn != null){
            System.out.println("Sucess");
        } 
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Database ERROR");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error que muestra:

```
error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                                                      ^
error: unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    stmt.executeUpdate();
                      ^
```

Estoy usando `import java.sql.*;` seguramente sea algo que este pasando por alto

Alguna de idea de donde surge ese error o como solucionarlo??

Gracias

Comment: Cuando instancias `stmt`, debes hacerlo desde un try catch que atrape SQLException **o** debes hacer que la declaración del método incluya un throws SQLException para que se propague.

Comment: muchas gracias!!